# star-like patterns formed by arrays of cubes in viewport

Tags: 3d-view

I noticed these patterns:
[image]
The mesh you see is just the base cube duplicated 1000 times in x and y directions using an array modifier, spacing is 1.2.
This is no problem, I am just curious what causes this. Would I see this in real world as well, if I had 1000000 little cubes evenly spaced in front of me, or is this the result of the computing. I tried rendering this view, to see if this remains in the render as well, and it does, but the effect is way more subtle.
I know this question is kind of off topic, but I am really curious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would.  Those are known as "Moire patterns" and they occur in real life.  The wikipedia page goes into great detail:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern

You can even see it in this photo of a normal striped shirt!

[image]

Comment: I think the interference here is between the resolution of the monitor and the cubes (since If I render a High resolution picture and zoom in, the waves disapear), which would suggest, that I wouldn't see this should I actually have real cubes in front of me.

Comment: yes, it's definitely resolution-dependent.  You might not see it with cubes of the same size, but small enough cubes would definitely exhibit the same phenomenon.